# How to indicate direction with Skobbler polylines?

Tags: skmaps

I'm building an offline driving tour app with skobbler. In the app there is a custom route for users to follow. I can draw the Polyline using SKPolyline class, but it'd be much better if there is a way to indicate the direction directly on the Polylines. For example, when you use skobbler's ForeverMap for routing, the app displays arrows on the route to indicate the direction.

What could be a possible way to do this?

Ideas considered:
1) Use multiple point routing, which I can use to connect all the tour destinations and use the provide direction. But this doesn't seem possible with Skobbler at this point.
2)Rotate map markers to point to the directions. Skobbler doesn't support this either.

Any advice is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Currently it's not possible to draw directed polylines (polylines with a direction arrow in them, similar to routes) with the SDK.
Neither is rotating map markers.

From 2.4 though, you will be able to create multi point routes - routes with via points (intermediate points) - the current ETA for 2.4 is end of February but you can have a peek at the 2.4 iOS beta build (that includes via points routing & navigation) using [cocoapods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK/2.4-beta1/ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK.podspec.json)